# Grocery CRUD cannot delete file

Tags: codeigniter, grocery-crud, delete-file

I'm having a problem in deleting files in grocery crud. When I upload file with comma `,` the file cannot be deleted the deleting file never stops, but when I upload files without comma `,` it can be deleted.

I checked the Network, when you inspect element, the code returns a Status code 400 and the response is

> The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could work for you:

In your config.php look for the line $config['permitted_uri_chars'] and add the comma.